# How to iterate the div items in HTML, and assign the value to each one?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I consumed an api created, where it will return a list with emails, I created a modal, with a div, where by the amount of emails returned, I want to add a div, and at the same time put the value of the emails in each one of them , the most I got was to put the same email in all of them, but at least I managed to add the amount of divs according to the number of emails returned, follows the code

```
<div class="modal">
    <h2>Lista</h2>
    <div id="list">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
modalList: (json) => {
        qS('.screen').style.justifyContent = 'center';
        qS('.screen').style.alignItems = 'center';
        qS('.rightside').style.display = 'none';
        qS('.modal').style.display = 'block';
        json.list.forEach((item, index)=>{
            let numeroHTML = ''
            for(let i = 0; i <= index; i++ ){
               numeroHTML += `<div class="result"></div>`;
            }
            qS('.modal #list').innerHTML = numeroHTML
            qSa('.result').forEach((result) => {
                result.innerHTML = item

            })
        });
    }
```

[image]

the logic that I'm not able to do is how to put each item in the array, that is, each email in a div only, and thus make a list in this modal

Comment: The problem seems to be in your nested loops.  Why is the "for" loop tied to index? Why do you generate the result divs in one loop and then populate them in a second loop?  To me, it seems you could remove the for loop and do everything in the forEach loop. Suggest you show some of your json, enough to understand the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create HTML from your array you can use a foreach loop like you're doing.
You should be using the HTML <ul> element with <li>s inside.
Do something like this for each iteration:

```js
const element = document.createElement('li')
element.innerText = item
list.appendChild(element)
```

```js
const json = {
  list: ["one", "two", "three"]
}

const listElement = document.querySelector('#list')
json.list.forEach((item, index) => {
  const element = document.createElement('li')
  element.classList.add('result')
  element.innerText = item
  list.appendChild(element)
});
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <h2>Lista</h2>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
/*
I'll assume the JSON is a typical array of objects and each object having a 
property/key "email" 
*/
const data=[{email:"tmcgowing0@netlog.com"},{email:"ckelsow1@usa.gov"},{email:"zwrench2@github.io"},{email:"avayne3@biblegateway.com"},{email:"mmarquis4@telegraph.co.uk"},{email:"pbrannigan5@marketwatch.com"},{email:"czannetti6@zimbio.com"},{email:"baspey7@thetimes.co.uk"},{email:"ejaumet8@tripadvisor.com"},{email:"pfellow9@cnbc.com"}];

/**
 * Renders a list in HTML from a given array of objects and a key.
 * @param {string<CSS>} selector - A CSS selector of the <ul>, <ol>, or <menu>
 * @param {array<object>} json - The data to make the list from
 * @param {string} key - The property/key to get the value from for the list
 */
const modalList = (selector, json, key) => {
  // Reference the list OR <body> (if undefined, null, etc)
  const node = document.querySelector(selector) || document.body;
  /*
  On each iteration through >json< render a htmlString into a <li> and add
  the current object's value of >key<
  */
  json.forEach(item => node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<li>${item[key]}</li>`));
};

/*
"click" event handler registered to button.open. When triggered the modal opens
and modalList() is called
*/
document.querySelector('.open').onclick = e => {
  document.querySelector('.modal').showModal();
  modalList('ul', data, 'email');
};

/* The rest is unrelated to question */
const UI = document.forms.UI;

UI.onclick = modalUI;
UI.onsubmit = funcX;

function modalUI(e) {
  const OG = e.target;

  if (OG.matches('.close')) {
    document.querySelector('.modal').close();
  }
};

function funcX(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.type + ' event fired');
};
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1.5 'Segoe UI'
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

dialog {
  margin: 10px auto;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 90%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px ridge grey
}

menu {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start
}

h3 {
  margin: 0 0 -8px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

section {
  width: 90%
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -35px
}

footer {
  width: 90%;
  border-top: 2px ridge grey;
}

.close {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <dialog class='modal'>
    <form id='UI'>
      <header>
        <h3>Email List</h3>
        <input class='btn close' type='button' value='X'>
      </header>
      <section>
        <ul></ul>
      </section>
      <footer>
        <menu>
          <button class='btn confirm'>Confirm</button>
          <button class='btn close' type='button'>Cancel</button>
        </menu>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </dialog>
  <menu>
    <button class='btn open'>Open Email List</button>
  </menu>
</main>
```

Comment: This is overkill xD

Comment: I have a tendency to overcompensate when there's lack of details. 